# How to set up aws Ec2 security group?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-ec2

How to set up aws Ec2 security group?

I am using reactnative. So I created an ec2 instance for the backend.
And I applied ssl to the backend.
In this case, how is it better to set the security group in the actual service?
First of all, this is how I set it up. Should I also add Http?
Also, how should I set ssh and https Source?

```
    Type    Protocol     Root Range     Source       Description
    SSH     TCP             22        0.0.0.0/0        –
    HTTPS   TCP             443       0.0.0.0/0        –
    HTTPS   TCP             443          ::/0          –
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you are actually asking. Are you asking how to create a Security Group through code, or are you asking whether your Security Group is correctly configured for your application? Does the Security Group meet your current requirements (that is, does it work)? More information, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some tips to improve your security group.

1. If you want to ssh to your instance then yes! you should open port 22, but open it to the whole internet is not something you should do. So you can limit ssh access to the instance by allowing port 22, just for the IP you are using to connect with the instance. You may think that's okay there is a rare chance that someone will try to ssh to my instance. But that's not true, if you enable vpc flow logs you may see how many people/scripts trying to get access to your instance.
2. Opening port 443 to the whole world is the correct thing to do. Perfect!
3. You should make the decision on opening port 80. If you don't want traffic on port 80, just keep it closed and make sure SSL is working on your application all the time. Cheers!